# Integrating getstream.io with Parse

Tags: parsing, parse-cloud-code, getstream-io

Is there a way to integrate getstream.io with Parse at all, so Cloud Code can send activities onto getstream?

What files are required from the getstream javascript api?

Answer (score 2):

**Example app**

We've actually done a small example app with Parse Cloud and getstream.io

Demo:
https://getstream.parseapp.com/

Code: https://github.com/tschellenbach/Stream-Example-Parse

Furthermore our JS client is now parse cloud compatible:
https://github.com/getstream/stream-js

**Background**

The example uses the after save and after delete hooks

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Picture", function(request, response) {
  // trigger fanout
  console.log("Picture Saved");
});
```

To have the client work with parse cloud we use the parse networking library
https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#networking
And wrap the API to make it seem somewhat similar to request.

Another issue is the support for Crypto. We've ended up using crypto browserify

https://github.com/dominictarr/crypto-browserify